# Vortex flow field in array

Tags: c++, objective-c, geometry, physics

I implemented a grid of vectors **in 2D** (in Obj-C actually, but I guess it's not really language dependent) which I'm able to fill with Simplex noise for example, to generate a **flow field** for **particles**.

I've been searching around and googling a lot, but as I'm not a mathematics expert I can't find a way to fill my grid with a Vortex (or at least a circular) flow field.

For the circle flow I thought about getting my vectors from tangents of circles getting from the outer grid lines to the inner ones.

But, for the vortex I just can't find any solution by myself.

The vortex is supposed to be symmetric and centered in my grid, but if there's an easy way to make it asymmetric in the same grid, well...

Comment: Is data flow supposed to be directed to a neighbour vertex or just a velocity? Is it 2D or 3D? Is the grid symmetric or randomly placed vertcies?

Answer (score 1):

Still some questions marks on the field. But if i get you right it is a velocity field you want. In other words a velocity in each vertex. 
For circular field you only need to take the orthogonal relative position vector to create a to get a circular field.

`v_t = (Py-Ry,Rx-Px)`

where `P` is the position of the vertex and `R` is the center of the field. The suffix x and y is just the corresponding coordinates.

To add a radial component to the velocity field just add some velocity in the radial direction. I can't tell if this will be stable when you simulate.

The radial direction is easily described as

`v_r = (Rx-Px,Ry-Py)`

and the use

`v = a*v_r+(1-a)*v_t`

with a good value for `a`, probably rather low.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Unfortunately, the circular flow take my particles outside of the circle. Would you have any tip to add a force to each cell pointing toward the center of the circle ?